# psql login issues in docker entrypoint.sh script

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

```
#!/bin/sh

until nc -vz postgresql 5432 &>/dev/null; do
    sleep 1
done

if [ "$( psql -h postgresql -U postgres -w -tAc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname='devdb'" )" = '1' ]
then
    echo "Database already exists"
else
     echo "Running db creation & init routines"
fi

exec "$@"
```

I have two containers 1. postgresql 2. graphql service (both are alpine based)
I have the above script (shortened) in my entrypoint.sh which is called as part of the graphql service's dockerfile. When I run the container in docker-compose, I get the error as

```
dss-graphql                 | psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I have set the `PGPASSWORD` in the `postgresql` container. (also set the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` just and added measure).

I can run the command psql command inside the container and get the result as `1`. When the same is run from entry point script it says `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Any ideas about this behavior ? copying/including the `postgresql` docker image entrypoint.sh is not something I want to do.

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  # postgresql 
  postgresql        :
    container_name  : postgresql
    hostname        : postgresql
    image           : postgres:10-alpine
    volumes         : 
                    - /var/lib/postgres/data
    networks        : 
                    - backend
    ports           : 
                    - 5432:5432
    restart         : on-failure
    env_file        :
                    - database.env 
  # dss-graphql
  dss-graphql             :
    container_name        : dss-graphql
    hostname              : dss-graphql
    build                 :
      dockerfile          : dss-graphql.dev.dockerfile
      context             : ${PWD}/dss-graphql
    image                 : dss-graphql
    volumes               :
                          - ${PWD}/dss-graphql:/dss-graphql
                          - /usr/local/bundle
    networks              :
                          - backend
    ports                 :
                          - 3016:3000
    tty                   : true
    stdin_open            : true
    depends_on            :
                          - postgresql
networks  :
  backend :
    driver: bridge
```

database.env contains

```
POSTGRES_DB=devdb
PGUSER=postgres
PGPASSWORD=secret
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
``
```

Comment: can you share your `docker-compose.yml` in the post too?

Comment: @richyen updated with `docker-compose.yml` content.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to add an `environment` section in your `dss-graphql` container, and include `- PGPASSWORD: "secret"`

Another option would be to create a `.pgpass` file and have it copied to your `dss-graphql` container

In short, you define the user/password in your `postgresql` container, but you don't seem to tell the `dss-graphql` container how to log in to the database, so it seems that you need to add that either as 1) an environment variable, 2) a password file (`.pgpass`), or 3) a parameter in some dss-graphql config (which I'm not very familiar with--sorry!)

More information about `.pgpass` can be found [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html)